# Mysql copy data from one database to another WHERE

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to copy data from one database into another. Essentially, I have 2 databases.

- Customer (which has ID, Name, DOB, Address)
- Full Customer (which has ID, PHOTO, SIGNATURE)(expanding to include Name, DOB, Address)

All customers are stored in the Customer database (10 million records), but only some are stored in the "Full Customer" database. (5 million records).

I want to copy all the Customer records into the Full Customer database where there is no record currently.

My pseudo code is below for programming, but i am wondering if i can do this directly with mysql

```
for customer in customers:
    if customer.ID not in (select ID from fullcustomer)
        insert customer into fullcustomer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and you *should* do it directly with MySQL.

Try this. I assumed tables are in the same database - if not, you should prefix the table names with database names. I also assumed missing columns in full_customer table are already there (you have put it there).

It basically means: "Insert into table full_customer records of users from table customer, that are not already there, using ID for comparison".

```
INSERT INTO full_customer (ID, Name, DOB, Address) (
   SELECT ID, Name, DOB, Address FROM customer c
   LEFT JOIN full_customer fc ON c.ID = fc.ID
   WHERE fc.ID IS NULL
)
```

What you should do is to do a sanity check beforehands, to check whether the provided SQL will select the customers you actually want to insert to the full_customer table:

```
SELECT ID, Name, DOB, Address FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN full_customer fc ON c.ID = fc.ID
WHERE fc.ID IS NULL
```

Make sure the ID column in both tables is indexed, otherwise it will take forever to execute these statements.

Comment: this worked great. Thanks for the help. The join worked great - needed a lot of testing as you mentioned.